# Histogram one array based on another array

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have two numpy arrays:

```
rates = [1.1, 0.8...]
zenith_anlges = [45, 20, ....]
```

both `rates` and `zen_angles` have the same length.

I also have some pre-defined `zenith_angle bins`,

`zen_bins = [0, 10, 20,...]`

What I need to do is bin the `rates` according to its corresponding zenith angle bins.

An ugly way to do it is

```
nbin = len(zen_bins)-1 
norm_binned_zen = [[0]]*nbin 
for i in range(nbin):
    norm_binned_zen[i] = [0]
for i in range(len(rates)):
    ind = np.searchsorted(zen_bins,zen_angles[i]) #The corresponding bin number
    norm_binned_zen[ind-1].append(rates[i])
```

This is not very pythonic and is time consuming for large arrays. I believe there must be some more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The starting data (here randomly generated):

```
import numpy as np

rates = np.random.random(100)
zenith_angles = np.random.random(100)*90.0
zen_bins = np.linspace(0, 90, 10)
```

Since you are using `numpy`, you can use a one line solution:

```
norm_binned_zen = [rates[np.where((zenith_angles > low) & (zenith_angles <= high))] for low, high in zip(zen_bins[:-1], zen_bins[1:])]
```

Breaking this line into steps:

- The list comprehension loops over pairs, the `low` and `hight` edges of each bin.
- [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is used to find the indexes of the angles inside the given bin in the `zenith_angles` array.
- numpy [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) is used to select the `rates` values at the indexes obtained at previous step.